# how to cite with restatable just an item of a theorem

Tags: citing

I have a theorem whith five items in the chapter 1 written with a restatable

```
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{maintheo}
\label{main teorema}
Sea $H$ un grupo amenable, sea $G$ un grupo y $G\wrwr H$ el producto corona irrestricto de $G$ con $H$. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Si $G$ es débilmente sófico, entonces $G\wrwr H$ es débilmente sófico.         \label{caso weak sofic}
\item Si $G$ es sófico, entonces $G\wrwr H$ es sófico. \label{caso sofic}
\item Si $G$ es linealmente sófico, entonces $G\wrwr H$ es linealmente sófico.     \label{caso linear sofic}
\item Si $G$ es hiperlineal, entonces $G\wrwr H$ es hiperlineal. \label{caso     hyperlineal}
\end{enumerate}
\end{restatable}
```

I need to repeat just the first item and not all the theorem (when I write \maintheo* it repeat all the theorem) but just the first item (indeed, I have to repeat the items one by one). So I would like to stay the numbering of the theorem but just repeat the item that I want. Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer a partial version of theorem restating. I assume that the restatement happens after the main statement.

I recommend against spaces in labels, so I replaced them with hyphens.

I also guessed what `\wrwr` should be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting,es-notilde]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % use the parent counter for your setting
\newtheorem*{auxtheorem}{Theorem \auxtheoremnumber} % for the repetitions

\newcommand{\wrwr}{\mathbin{\wr\wr}}

\newcommand{\restatabletheoremitem}[2]{%
  % #1 = label
  % #2 = text
  #2\label{#1}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname restate@#1\endcsname{%
    \begingroup
    \def\noexpand\auxtheoremnumber{\thetheorem.\noexpand\ref{#1}}%
    \unexpanded{\begin{auxtheorem}#2\end{auxtheorem}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand{\restatetheoremitem}[1]{%
  % #1 = label
  \ifcsname restate@#1\endcsname
    \csname restate@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \ERROR
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Main theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{main-teorema}
Sea $H$ un grupo amenable, sea $G$ un grupo y $G\wrwr H$ 
el producto corona irrestricto de $G$ con $H$. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item \restatabletheoremitem{caso-weak-sofic}{Si $G$ es débilmente sófico, 
  entonces $G\wrwr H$ es débilmente sófico.}
\item \restatabletheoremitem{caso-sofic}{Si $G$ es sófico, entonces $G\wrwr H$ es sófico.}
\item \restatabletheoremitem{caso-linear-sofic}{Si $G$ es linealmente sófico, 
  entonces $G\wrwr H$ es linealmente sófico.}
\item \restatabletheoremitem{caso-hyperlineal}{Si $G$ es hiperlineal, entonces
  $G\wrwr H$ es hiperlineal.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\section{Restatements}

\restatetheoremitem{caso-weak-sofic}

\restatetheoremitem{caso-sofic}

\restatetheoremitem{caso-linear-sofic}

\restatetheoremitem{caso-hyperlineal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you help!